# how can i use multiple jquery version in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

how can i use thisthree jquery versions in the same page ,i'am using different codes from differents tutorial that uses different jquery version  :

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>      
    <script src="iview/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Thank you

Comment: [this?](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Comment: How about using most recent jquery version and writing some code (instead of copy-pasting it from obsolete tutorials)?

Comment: Do not do this!

Comment: The third is ui script, you can use, for the first two, try to add only one and see which version is ok for all of your codes. v1.7.1 or v1.9.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21736074/3300831

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that you really don't need 2 versions of jQuery on the same page. It won't really help. If a certain script doesn't work with a particular version of jQuery, it doesn't mean that you can't use that script. It means that you might have to re-write some parts of the function to be more compatible. Certain functions, such as `live` and `click` depreciate after some versions. Just use one or the other.