# Including More Than One jQuery Versions

Tags: jquery

Trying to load these 3 with no conflict. But, there still is a conflict.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
$j( "#selector" ).click(function() {
alert("hello");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Update the plugin code, don't include multiple versions of jQuery.

Comment: So, just use the latest one? 1.9.1?

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` is your friend if you absolutely need those plugins.

Comment: I've tried no conflict! No luck with that.

Comment: What problems are you having, now? What conflicts?

Comment: I have colorbox and fadeslideshow on same page, plus one more jQuery version, which is the 1.8.3. But the colorbox is not working, it won't load. This must be because there is a conflict, correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/);

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($i.fn.jquery);
</script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($j.fn.jquery);
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($k.fn.jquery);
</script>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PGLVs/)

Comment: @juanberas fixed it and included a jsFiddle link.

Comment: Hmmm..I tried that and it didn't do the trick. I have colorbox, fade slideshow on same page plus one more jQuery version. But the colorbox pop up when you click Contact won't load. Link: http://shop.earartbyjaniyah.com/

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code here? Just edit your questions so other community members can see it as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) you can use multiple jQuery at a time. See this example.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($i.fn.jquery);
</script> 


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($j.fn.jquery);
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($k.fn.jquery);
</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/opkgdwLy/1).