# Slider is not working and I've got TypeError: jQuery(...).easyResponsiveTabs is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Okay what I have is a **wordpress** website: http://reformpackagingmachine.com

I have a slider problem and I'm getting this error :

**"TypeError: jQuery(...).easyResponsiveTabs is not a function"**

***activate: function(event) { // Callback function if tab is switched***

on firebug -which I think is another problem than bxSlider-

I wasn't the one that made the website, but the prev. developer ran away and I have to fix this.

I knew that errors like this might because of the paths of jQuery or jQuery ui files but I've checked it.

When I tried to validate at http://validator.w3.org it was giving errors about some `<link>` elements , because they were in the *footer.php* file. So I moved them to the *header.php* and it validated.

So my sliders(both horizontal and vertical)are not working, and I don't really get why I'm having this error. I mean what it has to do with sliders??

So here is my head markup,

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<script src="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/tabs/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/tabs/css/easy-responsive-tabs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

This is the markup for slider:

```
<div class="the-main-slider-container">
<ul class="bxslider">

    <li>
        <img alt="slider" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/slider-1.jpg">
    </li>

    <li>
        <img alt="slider" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/slider-2.jpg">
    </li>

    <li>
        <img alt="slider" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/slider-3.jpg">
    </li>

    <li>
        <img alt="slider" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/slider-4.jpg">
    </li>

    <li>
        <img alt="slider" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/slider-5.jpg">
    </li>

</ul>

<div id="bx-pager">
<div class="pager-wrapper">
    <div class="pager-container">
        <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img alt="icone" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/D320-icone-features-features.png"></a>
        <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img alt="icone" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/D320-icone-features-confezioni.png"></a>
        <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img alt="icone" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/D320-icone-features-vantaggi.png"></a>
        <a data-slide-index="3" href=""><img alt="icone" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/D320-icone-features-specifiche.png"></a>
        <a data-slide-index="4" href=""><img alt="icone" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/d320-icone-compact2.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the script for bxslider:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery.noConflict();

         jQuery(document).ready(function() 
         {
            jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
                mode: 'fade'
            });

         });  

        jQuery(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.slider8').bxSlider({
            mode: 'vertical',
            slideWidth: 300,
            minSlides: 2,
            slideMargin: 10
          });
        }); 
        });

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 450,
                maxHeight   : 400,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
        });

        </script>
```

And this is the script for easyResponsiveTabs:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
               jQuery('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs({
                    type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion           
                    width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
                    fit: true,   // 100% fit in a container
                    closed: 'accordion', // Start closed if in accordion view
                    activate: function(event) { // Callback function if tab is switched
                        var $tab = jQuery(this);
                        var $info = jQuery('#tabInfo');
                        var $name = jQuery('span', $info);

                        $name.text($tab.text());

                        $info.show();
                      }
                   });
                });
            </script>
```

I know it looks confusing but I'm sure you can see better if you go to the link and check it. You will see it looks pretty bad now and it's online!

And if I missed any necessary info on this description, please tell me so that I can add it.

So I'm completely open to all kinds of useful information. Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit #1** I've tried using *noConflict* like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
            j(document).ready(function () {
               j('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs({
                    type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion           
                    width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
                    fit: true,   // 100% fit in a container
                    closed: 'accordion', // Start closed if in accordion view
                    activate: function(event) { // Callback function if tab is switched
                        var $tab = jQuery(this);
                        var $info = jQuery('#tabInfo');
                        var $name = jQuery('span', $info);

                        $name.text($tab.text());

                        $info.show();
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
```

but it didn't work and I've got the same error...

Comment: Here's an example on how to use jQuery .noConflict() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735713/including-more-than-one-jquery-versions/21736074#21736074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying lots of different things, I've managed to solve my own problem. I've put the JavaScript files for bxSlider, easyResponsiveTabs and the scripts calling them to footer.php. But I've left the jQuery & jQuery UI files at the header.php along with the css files for the sliders.

Now everything is working well and the markup passed the validation test! If you're having same kind of error;

1. Check your jQuery and other JavaScript file paths.
2. Check if you're using an old version of jQuery or uncompatible
   versions of jQuery & jQuery UI.
3. Don't work with really stupid developers that may put your link
   files to footer.php...
4. Check if you have different instances and versions of jquery.min.js
5. (For my situation) Put your bxSlider js files to footer.php but
   leave the css files in header.php (for validation, just this way it
       worked well)

Also you can write here, I can try to help you.