# JQuery.js WordPress conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that uses the *jQuery Mega Menu plugin* and *theme-my-login* both call:

```
<script type='text/javascript'src='http://localhost/wadhaa/dynamic/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
```

in my head section by:

```
<?php
    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
   ?>
```

and I have to include:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

which causes conflicts with WordPress jquery.js

Can anyone can help me fix this? or let me know at least why this conflict happen.

The error I get from this conflict is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Why would you have to load jQuery twice? The versions are nearly identical.

Comment: Don't load jQuery twice... simple. Use the `1.11.1` version only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21736074/3300831

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including More Than One jQuery Versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735713/including-more-than-one-jquery-versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include your own jQuery, Wordpress have included it, but the `$` name was reserved.

just call:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#what_ever_you_want').do_something();
});
```