# how to resolve the conflict between jquery UI and Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile with jquery UI . I have added them like :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

as suggested in documentation I have added Jquery UI before Jquery mobile . but I am getting the conflict between this two libraries . **I am using Jquery UI only for sorting the list** . So before that I have also tried to add jQuery.noConfict() like this 
//function which using jquery UI

```
function sort()
{
  jQuery.noConfict();
  // after this I am using jQuery instead of $
}
//function that not using jquery UI
function delete()
{
//here I want to use $ again 
}
```

but this approach not worked for me . please suggest some solution .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21736074/3300831

Answer (score 2):

I thing you should resolve conflict like following

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_9_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script> <br />
```

Now use `jQuery_1_9_1` as `$` for jQuery version `1.9.1`.

Comment: I think I already tried that ,can we please explain with reference of my above methods ?

Comment: I am sorry for late. response.function sort()
{
  jQ=$.noConfict(true);
 }. Now use jQ instead of $ or jQuery (jQ now global var)